# Pass arguments to JavaScript function from Sightly

Tags: aem, sightly

I can call JavaScript functions from Sightly with no parameters, e.g.

```
<div
    data-sly-use.ResourceUtils="/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/ResourceUtils.js"
    data-example="${ResourceUtils.aFunction}" />
```

But I would like to call a function called 'getResource' that accepts 1 argument.

How can I address this function from Sightly, passing in this argument?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to pass a parameter to eighter Java or JavaScript Sightly class. Take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065552/aem6-sightly-how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-html-to-a-method-from-java-model-clas

Answer (score 4):

basically, you can access arguments by using "this.", for example:

Your html would look something like this:

```
<div data-sly-use.ResourceUtils="${'/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/ResourceUtils.js' @ arg='argument'}" data-example="${ResourceUtils.aFunction}" />
```

And the JS would be:

```
use( function () {
  var argument = this.arg;
```